# Army Composition EA. Need help designing Selection and Mutation Operator

Tags: artificial-intelligence, evolutionary-algorithm

I am trying to build (part of) an AI for a game I created.

**Problem description**

Given a certain pool of available units, and a specific composition of the army of the enemy (the human player), use an Evolutionary Algorithm to create a composition of units from the available pool that will defeat the enemy's army.

There are several types of units in this game, most of them compete against each other in a *rock-paper-scissors* fashion, meaning unit type A will defeat B, B will defeat C and C will defeat A. The most expensive unit isn't always the best. If the enemy's army is diverse, we need to be diverse as well.

Unit cost is a rough estimate of its power. 1 type A unit costing 100 is about equal to 10 type B units which cost 10 each. However, this is *slightly* offset by the *rock-paper-scissors* characteristics of the units.

**Constraints**

1. Keep the army as small as possible. Larger armies require more upkeep resources to fight.
2. Keep the losses as small as possible, should never exceed the spoils of the fight (loot after a win), at least for normal difficulties.

**EA Components**

1. Initialization: Create N compositions at random from the pool of available units.
2. Fitness: Technically most complex, but already done: Simply simulate within the space of my own game.
3. Operators: Which genetic operators to use to evolve each army composition to possibly improve. So far I haven't had much success with this.

The meat of the problem, I believe, lies in the genetic operators. I have tried different approaches, but all seem to either at best get stuck in local optima or seem completely random (each rerun of the algorithm against the same opponent seems to produce wildly different results).

I have tried the following operators with poor to no results:

- For each unit, with probability *p*, change its type from A to B
- For each unit, with probability *p*, replace it with as much units of type B so current cost remains same.
- For each unit, with probability *p*, remove it without replacement
- For each composition, with probability *p*, add 1 unit of a random type to it

So, my question is, given this problem description, what would be decent mutation and combination operators? I feel the operators I have used so far are all too focused on the local environment (add 1, change 1, remove 1) and don't fully use the potential of the EA.

Comment: How do you exactly calculate the fitness?

Comment: I simply simulate the battle and compare the outcome. My losses vs the loot from the enemy (player). The net total could be positive or negative. Upkeep is added to the losses to converge on a smaller more specific army tailored to the specific battle. Else the largest army consisting of all possible units winning in a landslide would always be the best.

Answer (score 0):

I would try separating the army in different squads, for each unit type in the beginning. Depending of the size of each squad, you could split it up into several smaller ones. This would give you the option of duplicating squads and doing crossover with other genomes to get a more varied result.

If this doesn't help I would try to mix the squads with other types, but still keeping them small. They would be suspect to the same mutations you already have in place.

I've had similar problems of my mutations sometimes being too high and other times being too small, resulting in the same (too random vs local optima) problems you've run in. Adding the crossover mechanisms and lowering the mutation rate at the same time eliminated them for me.

It's a 3 week old question, did you have any success in the mean time?